# Generic detail view --userprofile link with post author

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to view post author profile page from blog detail page and for that

```
#views.py
class UserProfileView(DetailView):
    model = Userinfo
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
    slug_field = 'username'
    template_name = "accounts/userinfo.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserProfileView, self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
        context['author_page'] = get_object_or_404(Userinfo, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return context
```

and the url has to something like http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/test2/

```
path('profile/<str:username>/', UserProfileView.as_view(), name='user_profile'),
```

postdetail page

```
<a href="{% url 'user_profile' username=post.author.username %}">{{ post.author.username }}</a>
```

and model.py

```
class Userinfo(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(accountUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=800)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Post models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    cover = models.URLField(blank=True)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, default=0)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(accountUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
class accountUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email             = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username          = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined       = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login        = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin          = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active         = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff          = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser      = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The Error is

```
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Test2'.
```

I tried many solution but nothing worked. Please help me.

Comment: We need to know about the accountUser model.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your `Userinfo` model, `slug_field` should be `username__username` to found Userinfo which User has given username.

```py
class UserProfileView(DetailView):
    model = Userinfo
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
    slug_field = 'username__username' # Userinfo a a foreignKey to User through `username` field
    template_name = "accounts/userinfo.html"
    context_object_name = "author_page" # the retrieved Userinfo instance is passed to the template as `author_page` variable
```

Comment: Post model author field is a ForeignKey to accountUser.----author = models.ForeignKey(accountUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: I still get error. I Updated the question Please see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I made some changes and getting ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Test2'.Can you see my urls and views.py .If you can find any mistake.Thank you